# Google Maps JavaScript API V3 - API Key and clientId

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

After reading many online forums/blogs, it's pretty clear to me that Google Maps API V3 do not require API key anymore.
And for more advanced google map features, I should have clientId (which my organisation already have).

But what is confusing to me is that I found two places -

First, where I get the information that *API key is still good to use*
'All Maps API applications should load the Maps API using an API key'
[Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html)

Second, where I get information that we *should definitely avoid using API key* and replace them with clientId
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-V3/oJf7I5FdAdY
http://egis3.lacounty.gov/eGIS/2011/12/06/google-maps-api-v3-to-stop-ignoring-the-key-parameter/

Can please guide if I am missing something and which one should I take as the correct information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if the documentation says "All Maps API applications should load the Maps API using an API key," then that is the advice to follow. It's probably better advice than postings in a forum (including, perhaps, this one).

It's true that Version 3 **will work** without a key; but there is no guarantee that they will continue to do so, particularly in the light of the documentation; and using a key brings the benefits of statistics reporting.

The client ID is associated with an Enterprise licence, which raises some of the limits associated with a ordinary free key. Neither unlocks advanced features of the *map*; both allow usage reporting.

Comment: what do you mean when you say - *Neither unlocks advanced features of the map* I think buying clientId does allow for some advanced features (from documentation @http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/business/guide.html **To access the special features of Google Maps API for Business, you must provide a client ID...**) Any comments?

Comment: If you [read this bit](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/business/guide.html#WhyPremier) it tells you what's extra. It uses the "same codebase as the standard Google Maps API": additional mapping features aren't included.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have missed something !
The two links you give at the end of your question relate to moving from v2 of the API (where a key was obligatory) to v3 of the API where a key is optional.

It is not necessary to have a key for v3 of the API if you will not have more than 25000 map loads per day.
Over this limit, it is apparently required that you obtain a key and a premium account (payable).
Ensure that you have really understood the contents of the first link you gave, notably the section [Obtaining an API key](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#api_key).
Then jump to the linked page on [Usage Limits](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/usage.html#usage_limits).

I reiterate what I have said : it is NOT required that you have an API key for v3.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Can you also please guide between - getting an API key license (for map advanced features) OR - getting a clientId - what is the major difference between these two? Thank you!

Comment: If you've got a client id I suggest you get in contact with the support folks at Google [http://support.google.com/enterprisehelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142244#maps] who can help straighten this out.